go mod conflict with v2 pre-release
I am developing version 2 of my hap package, which is a HTTP API framework.  Version 2 is not ready yet, and the latest release ls v2.0.0-alpha.2, like so:
* 9319436 - bug fix, refined action error output (HEAD -> master, tag: v2.0.0-alpha.2, origin/master, origin/HEAD) (16 hours ago) <xrfang>
* 2b1046a - various improvements (20 hours ago) <xrfang>
* 464dcb7 - example: added source IP control and global logging (tag: v2.0.0-alpha.1) (2 days ago) <xrfang>
* 94d6607 - reversed finalizer execution order (2 days ago) <xrfang>
* 7604144 - added global actions and finalizers (2 days ago) <xrfang>
... ...

The directory structure of the entire repo is:
.
├── example
├── go.mod
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── v2
    ├── api
    ├── arg
    ├── example
    ├── go.mod
    ├── handler
    └── param

The go.mod under the root directory is:
module go.xrfang.cn/hap

go 1.17


while v2/go.mod looks like:
module go.xrfang.cn/hap/v2

go 1.22.1

The problem now is go failed to get the v2 pre-release, go mod tidy under a project using hap/v2:
go: downloading go.xrfang.cn/hap/v2 v2.0.0-alpha.2
go: usermgr imports
        go.xrfang.cn/hap/v2: go.mod has non-.../v2 module path "go.xrfang.cn/hap" at revision v2.0.0-alpha.2
go: usermgr imports
        go.xrfang.cn/hap/v2/api: go.mod has non-.../v2 module path "go.xrfang.cn/hap" at revision v2.0.0-alpha.2
go: usermgr imports
... ...

Using go get:
$ GOPROXY=direct go get -u -v -x go.xrfang.cn/hap/v2@v2.0.0-alpha.2
# get https://go.xrfang.cn/hap/v2?go-get=1
# get https://go.xrfang.cn/hap/v2?go-get=1: 200 OK (0.196s)
get "go.xrfang.cn/hap/v2": found meta tag vcs.metaImport{Prefix:"go.xrfang.cn/hap/v2", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://e.coding.net/xrfang/go/hap.git"} at //go.xrfang.cn/hap/v2?go-get=1
mkdir -p /home/xrfang/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs # git3 https://e.coding.net/xrfang/go/hap.git
# lock /home/xrfang/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/0f263e071aed73ec9ef118d38d27fc7cbbcc33f1c19bbac5423684b8b560e3f9.lock
# /home/xrfang/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/0f263e071aed73ec9ef118d38d27fc7cbbcc33f1c19bbac5423684b8b560e3f9 for git3 https://e.coding.net/xrfang/go/hap.git
cd /home/xrfang/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/0f263e071aed73ec9ef118d38d27fc7cbbcc33f1c19bbac5423684b8b560e3f9; git tag -l
0.002s # cd /home/xrfang/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/0f263e071aed73ec9ef118d38d27fc7cbbcc33f1c19bbac5423684b8b560e3f9; git tag -l
cd /home/xrfang/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/0f263e071aed73ec9ef118d38d27fc7cbbcc33f1c19bbac5423684b8b560e3f9; git -c log.showsignature=false log --no-decorate -n1 '--format=format:%H %ct %D' refs/tags/v2.0.0-alpha.2 --
0.003s # cd /home/xrfang/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/0f263e071aed73ec9ef118d38d27fc7cbbcc33f1c19bbac5423684b8b560e3f9; git -c log.showsignature=false log --no-decorate -n1 '--format=format:%H %ct %D' refs/tags/v2.0.0-alpha.2 --
cd /home/xrfang/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/0f263e071aed73ec9ef118d38d27fc7cbbcc33f1c19bbac5423684b8b560e3f9; git cat-file blob 931943650fcb745bf3219ad4bf1ca93177047a5a:go.mod
0.002s # cd /home/xrfang/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/0f263e071aed73ec9ef118d38d27fc7cbbcc33f1c19bbac5423684b8b560e3f9; git cat-file blob 931943650fcb745bf3219ad4bf1ca93177047a5a:go.mod
go: go.xrfang.cn/hap/v2@v2.0.0-alpha.2: go.mod has non-.../v2 module path "go.xrfang.cn/hap" at revision v2.0.0-alpha.2


Seems like you followed the documentation to the letter. One thing that I noticed is that the error message in your case refers to "go.mod has non-.../v2 module path", with a slash in there ("/v2"). If I search for that error message in Google, it generally is without a slash like here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33154 . An odd difference that might be nothing (a result of a newer version of Go perhaps) or it might point to something strange in your setup.

I can't access your module directly, but it fetches correctly via the proxy. Perhaps you have corrupted something locally, maybe clear out the cache entirely and see if that changes anything.

The problem is identified and fixed by help from go-nuts forum.  Problem is that my own go-get facade returned an incorrect meta tag.  It returned
<meta name="go-import" content="go.xrfang.cn/hap/v2 git https://e.coding.net/xrfang/go/hap.git">

While the correct tag should be:
<meta name="go-import" content="go.xrfang.cn/hap git https://e.coding.net/xrfang/go/hap.git">

Because /v2 is not the root of this repository.
